# C printf NSDATA (Objective C type)

Tags: c, printf, nsdata

I have NSDATA and NSMUTABLEDATA variables holding bytes and I want to print the values of Bytes in a XCODE output console.

I know the length of bytes inside these structures and I was looking for a function to do something like this

```
void PrintOutput(NSMUTABLEDATA _data,int size)
```

{
    foreach byte in NSMUTABLEDATA or NSDATA
          printf(byte)->>>> maybe cast this to string of what I am not sure

}

Comment: Not sure at all, but `printf([[_data description] UTF8String])`?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone looking to do something similar. Here is the answer

```
void print_bytes(void *ptr, int size)
{
     unsigned char *p = ptr;
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<size;i++)
     {
       printf("%02hhX ",p[i];
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```